# Is Z/p a finite field only when p is prime number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

In [Integer and modular addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group#Integer_and_modular_addition) of Cyclic group:

> The integer and modular addition operations, used to define the cyclic
>   groups, are both the addition operations of commutative rings, also
>   denoted Z and Z/n. If p is a prime, then Z/p is a finite field, and is
>   usually instead written as Fp or GF(p). Every field with p elements is
>   isomorphic to this one.

Per my understanding, the `Z/p` should be a finite field no matter p is prime or not, is it right?

Answer (score 3):

It'll be finite, but it won't be a field. A field requires that every element has a multiplicative inverse.

Take for example $Z/6$. In this ring, $2 \cdot 3 = 6 = 0$, but neither $2$ nor $3$ is zero. An elementary consequence of this is that neither of them can have multiplicative inverses.

Answer (score 1):

No; if $p$ is not prime, then $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is not a field. If $p$ is not prime, then let $ab=p$, where $a\neq 1,p$. Then in $\Bbb{Z}_p$, we have $ab = 0$. If $\Bbb{Z}_p$ were a field, then there would exist $c$ such that $ac = 1$. However, we would then have $b = cab = c\cdot 0 = 0$, which is false (if $b=0$ mod $p$ then $a=1$).

Answer (score 0):

An important sometimes overlooked addition to the provided answers:

Although there exist finite fields on $p^n$, it is not the case that $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is a field for $n>1$. $p^{k-1}$ and $p$ are both non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, but their product is obviously $p^n=0$. Constructions of finite fields for $n>1$ can be tricky, although there is a simple example for $n=2$ and $p=4k+3$ given by $$(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1))/(p)=\mathbb{Z}[i]/(p))\cong \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$$ The reason this fails to work for other values of $p$ is that $i$ is the solution to $x^2+1=0$, but this equation already has solutions when $p=4k+1$ and when $p=2$ which makes the reduction trivial.